# Why does my bool RemoveAll method only return false?

Tags: c#, stack, boolean

I have to create a RemoveAll method for a stack that takes out all of a particular value and then returns the other values back to the original stack. The method I wrote, however, just returns false. What is the error in my code?

Here's the method I wrote:

```
public bool RemoveAll(T item)
{
    Stack<T> OurStack = new Stack<T>();
    Stack<T> tempStack = new Stack<T>();
    bool itemRemove = false;
    OurListNode<T> pTmp = mTop;

    while (OurStack.Count > 0)
    {
        if (pTmp.Data.Equals(item))
        {
            itemRemove = true;
            pTmp = pTmp.Next;
        }
        else
        {
            tempStack.Push(pTmp.Data);
        }
    }
    while (tempStack.Count > 0)
    {
        pTmp = pTmp.Next;
        OurStack.Push(pTmp.Data);
    }
    return itemRemove;
}
```

Here's the main I wrote to test the method:

```
static void Main()
{
    OurStack<int> nums = new OurStack<int>();
    nums.Push(1);
    nums.Push(31);
    nums.Push(22);
    nums.Push(3);
    //nums.RemoveAll(31);

    Console.Write(nums.RemoveAll(1));
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What is `OurListNode<T> pTmp = mTop;`, What is the break condition for two `while` loops. You seems to be only pushing data ion stack, where it is popping it out and emptying the stack

Comment: The break conditions for the two while loops should be the emptying of the stacks OurStack and tempStack. However, the method isn't recognizing that any data is being put in at all as MajkeloDev pointed out. I'm using pTmp as a temporary pointer to the top of the stack. So when I wrote pTmp = pTmp.Next--I'm attempting to pop it out of its frame, analyze its contents, and then either remove it from the stack entirely or place it in tempStack, but that isn't happening because I never actually make it past the while loop line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that:

> (OurStack.Count > 0)

and

> (tempStack.Count > 0)

Will always be false as when function starts you initialize OurStack and tempStack with new object so it will always be empty(unless you are adding something in Stack constructor code):

```
Stack<T> OurStack = new Stack<T>();
Stack<T> tempStack = new Stack<T>();
```

So those list will always be empty ...

Comment: When the method is used, I call it after I have added to our stack and shouldn't the first while statement be pushing data into tempStack? So why are the lists still empty? When I debug it goes first through the process of adding to the list--so I know that OurStack contains data. But you're right that it is identifying them as empty because it goes to the first while statement, then to the second and then returns the original value of ItemRemove which is false. Any idea why?

Comment: @Stephanie you marked my answer as correct. Do you understand it now, or you want me to give you some more explanations ?

Comment: I could see when debugging the program that you were right--I just don't know how to fix it--so if you have time to explain a bit more, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the line - if (pTmp.Data.Equals(item)) is never returning true, thereby never switching the bool. put a breakpoint there to see.

Comment: That's the weird thing; when I debug it goes to the first while statement and then jumps to the next while statement without walking through any other code. I have no idea why it is doing that...

Answer (score 0):

Is **OurStack** the name of a variable or a type? In the RemoveAll method it is used as a variable name and in the test method it is used as a type.